# Why does using 'Range.ImportFragment' followed by 'ActiveDocument.WordOpenXML' cause a crash?

Tags: crash, ms-word, vsto

I am using MS Word 2013. I have created a very simple VSTO 2013 Word Add-in project. To this project I have added a Ribbon (Designer version rather than XML), to which I have added a Button.

The Button has a Click event as follows:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    var app = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;

    app.Selection.Range.ImportFragment("PathToAnotherWordDocument");

    var openXML = app.ActiveDocument.WordOpenXML;
}
```

I then 'F5' to build and start the Add-in. Once word has started, I click on the button.
This causes Word to crash (it is Word itself crashing, not the Add-in).

The file located at `PathToAnotherWordDocument` is a simple Word Document containing a single paragraph with a couple of words.

If I step through the code everything works fine until I reach the `app.ActiveDocument.WordOpenXML` line. As soon as I step onto this, the crash happens.

It also happens if I examine this property in the Watch Window, i.e. I scroll down the list of properties for 'app.AtiveDocument' and, as soon as `WordOpenXML` is in view, Word crashes. All other properties in the Watch Window appear to be fine.

If I comment out the offending line, leaving just the `ImportFragment` statement then I can continue to use Word just fine. I see the words from the other Word Document have indeed been imported and I can continue to edit without any problems.

Why is this happening? How can I stop it from happening?

**EDIT**

I have worked out how to stop it from happening: if I assign the `app.ActiveDocument.Content.WordOpenXML` property to a variable first, the `app.ActiveDocument.WordOpenXML` property then magically starts working again.

Although this is a solution to my immediate issue, I would still like to know why the crash happens if I access the Document's WordOpenXML property directly.

Comment: If I save the offending document and then reopen it, the 'WordOpenXML' property works just fine. So there is nothing wrong with the document structure, as such...

Comment: Out of curiosity -- which version of Word are you using: 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: 32bit Word on 64bit Windows 8.